# Use of an interface in unit tests

Tags: java, testing, junit, mockito

Why is it advised to use an interface whilst carrying out unit tests using the Mockito framework?What exactly is the use of an interface in unit testing?

Comment: I would say that you would always want to mock an interface rather than a concrete class if the class under test accepts a interface as a parameter. If you mock a specific implementation of the interface then it might look to someone else reading the code like the class under test only accepts that implementation as parameter. Rather mocking the interface will also expose if someone did something nasty in the code under test such as casting the interface parameter up to a specific concrete implementation (this will cause a class cast exception).

Answer (score 0):

There are two reasons: one theoretical, and one practical.

#### Theory

When working with a mock, you are providing a *test double* of a component that exists (or will exist) elsewhere in your application; when stubbing you are simulating the responses that the real implementation would have, and when verifying you're doing so against the class's external interface. This makes it very important to have a clear definition of what successful implementors of the interface *should* be doing and how they *should* be behaving, regardless of the current implementation: you're providing a different implementation.

Though you could document your implementation's contract method-by-method on the concrete class itself, another method of documenting and formalizing the general contract of the component is to extract an interface. Though I'm no proponent of prospective work (see [YAGNI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/You_aren%27t_gonna_need_it)), doing so also makes it clearer if you were to partially or entirely replace your current concrete implementation with another implementation—at which point you would have three implementations of the interface including the mock, and might want to write a test purely against the interface and pass each implementation in separately for verification/validation between them.

#### Practice

Internally, Mockito dynamically creates your test double by *generating a subclass* of the class you're trying to test. This means that your mock can only override behavior that a normal subclass can override, and that can make Mockito ill-suited for private classes, encapsulated nested or inner classes, and final classes. In addition, for similar reasons, you will find yourself unable to mock static methods, final methods, and some private or protected methods (particularly wherever which the compiler generates [synthetic methods](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2073578/java-s-synthetic-methods.html)).  Because of Mockito's syntax and dynamic nature, Java can't warn about or enforce these rules at compile time, and Mockito can't always detect violations at runtime.

However, when mocking *interfaces* rather than *concrete implementations*, Mockito can avoid much of this trouble. Interfaces have no internal method visibility restrictions or final methods, and the types themselves are necessarily public and non-final. So, from a practical standpoint, there are advantages in simplicity and ease of work that come with interfaces but not concrete classes.